# ruby NameError uninitialized constant only on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

so I have these code

```
require_relative '../classes/obj/objs.rb'

class ObjController < ActionController::Base

  def get_objs
    objs = Objs::get_objs
    render :json => objs
  end

end
```

and in objs.rb

```
module Objs

def Objs.get_objs
  objs = {
     1 => 2,
  }

  return objs 
end

end
```

on my vagrant environment the code runs fine, however when i upload to my EC2 instance, it ends up complaining:

```
NameError in ObjController#get_objs
uninitialized constant ObjController::Objs
```

both environments are using ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing your `Objs` with `::` like so...

```
require_relative '../classes/obj/objs.rb'

class ObjController < ActionController::Base

  def get_objs
    objs = ::Objs::get_objs
    render :json => objs
  end

end
```

Comment: I have the impression that require_relative is not working for some reason